# Facebook Pixel:AddPaymentInfo for Shopify (How to implement it correctly?)

Tags: javascript, facebook, shopify, pixel

I have been extremely stuck with this one.

How would you implement Facebook tracking for AddPaymentInfo during checkout?

If I add the script below to Settings --> Checkout --> Additional Scripts, then 'AddPaymentInfo' fires after checkout not DURING.

```
*<script>
fbq('track', 'AddPaymentInfo');
</script>*
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no proper way other than going to Shopify Plus, but you may try use the custom JavaScript section for Google Analytics. https://freakdesign.com.au/blogs/news/18544989-adding-javascript-to-shopify-checkout